# TypeError: AbiCoder is not a constructor, testing purchaseSnack function is failing. I think due to not handling ether conversion correctly

Tags: ether, abi, constructor, function

I am trying to write a test script using hardhat to test the purchaseSnack function but I keep receiving these errors.

````
 1) VendingMachine
       Should fail if insufficient funds are sent:
     TypeError: AbiCoder is not a constructor
      at decodeReturnData (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/reverted/utils.ts:65:15)
      at onError (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/reverted/revertedWith.ts:45:51)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/VendingMachineTest.js:27:5)

  2) VendingMachine
       Should fail if invalid snack is selected:
     TypeError: AbiCoder is not a constructor
      at decodeReturnData (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/reverted/utils.ts:65:15)
      at onError (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/reverted/revertedWith.ts:45:51)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/VendingMachineTest.js:35:5)

  3) VendingMachine
       Should fail if trying to purchase more snacks than available:
     TypeError: AbiCoder is not a constructor
      at decodeReturnData (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/reverted/utils.ts:65:15)
      at onError (node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/reverted/revertedWith.ts:45:51)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:533:9)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/VendingMachineTest.js:43:5)
    ```
    Here is my test script file
    ```javascript
    const { ethers } = require("hardhat")
const { expect, assert } = require("chai")

describe("VendingMachine", function () {
  let VendingMachineFactory, vendingMachine
  beforeEach(async function () {
    VendingMachineFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("VendingMachine")
    ;[owner, addr1, addr2, ...addrs] = await ethers.getSigners()
    vendingMachine = await VendingMachineFactory.deploy({
      value: ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0"),
    })
    await vendingMachine.deployed()
  })

  it("Should reduce quantity of the snack and increment the balance of contract", async function () {
    const initialBalance = await vendingMachine.getBalance()
    await vendingMachine
      .connect(addr1)
      .purchaseSnack("chips", 1, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001") })
    const finalBalance = await vendingMachine.getBalance()
    expect(finalBalance).to.equal(
      initialBalance.add(ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001")),
    )
  })

  it("Should fail if insufficient funds are sent", async function () {
    await expect(
      vendingMachine.connect(addr1).purchaseSnack("chips", 1, {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0005"),
      }),
    ).to.be.revertedWith("Declined! Insufficient payment amount.")
  })

  it("Should fail if invalid snack is selected", async function () {
    await expect(
      vendingMachine.connect(addr1).purchaseSnack("invalid", 1, {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.001"),
      }),
    ).to.be.revertedWith("Invalid snack selected")
  })

  it("Should fail if trying to purchase more snacks than available", async function () {
    await expect(
      vendingMachine.connect(addr1).purchaseSnack("chips", 21, {
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.021"),
      }),
    ).to.be.revertedWith("We've sold out of this item!")
  })

  it("Should return the balance of the vending machine", async function () {
    const contractBalanceBefore = await vendingMachine.getBalance()
    const amountToSend = ethers.utils.parseEther("1.0")

    // Send some funds to the contract
    await owner.sendTransaction({
      to: vendingMachine.address,
      value: amountToSend,
    })

    const contractBalanceAfter = await vendingMachine.getBalance()
    expect(contractBalanceAfter).to.equal(
      contractBalanceBefore.add(amountToSend),
    )
  })
})
````

Here is my smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

// import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract VendingMachine {
    /* Errors */
    error VendingMachine__OverStock(string message);
    error VendingMachine__TransferFailed();
    /* State Variables */
    // use address(this).balance to find the contract's balance
    uint256 public constant INITIAL_QUANTITY = 20;
    uint256 contractBalance = address(this).balance;

    address private immutable i_owner;

    string[] private snackNames;

    struct Snacks {
        uint256 quantity;
        uint256 price;
    }
    mapping(string => Snacks) public inventory;
    // tracks balances of each caller that interacts with the contract
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    /* Events */
    event Purchased(string msg, uint256 qtyPurchased, string snackPurchased);
    event WithdrawFunds(address ownerAccount, uint256 withdrawBalance);
    /*  Modifier */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == i_owner, "Not contract owner");
        _;
    }

    constructor() payable {
        i_owner = msg.sender;
        inventory["chips"] = Snacks(INITIAL_QUANTITY, 0.001 ether);
        inventory["drinks"] = Snacks(INITIAL_QUANTITY, 0.002 ether);
        inventory["cookies"] = Snacks(INITIAL_QUANTITY, 0.001 ether);
        snackNames.push("chips");
        snackNames.push("drinks");
        snackNames.push("cookies");
    }

    // receive function to handle ether being sent
    receive() external payable {
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    }

    // Function that takes in ether payment in exchange for specific snack
    function purchaseSnack(string calldata _snack, uint256 _quantity)
        public
        payable
    {
        Snacks storage snack = inventory[_snack];
        uint256 snackPrice = snack.price; // Retrieve the price based on the snack name

        require(snackPrice > 0, "Invalid snack selected"); // Verify that the snack price exists
        require(
            msg.value >= snackPrice,
            "Declined! Insufficient payment amount."
        ); // Verify that the payment is sufficient

        require(snack.quantity >= _quantity, "We've sold out of this item!"); // Verify the quantity of snacks in the vending machine
        snack.quantity -= _quantity;

        balances[msg.sender] += snackPrice; // accounts for the amount spent from customer
        contractBalance += snack.price; // accounts for revenue earned by vending machine

        emit Purchased("Thank you for your purchase of ", _quantity, _snack);
    }

    // Function to withdraw funds
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 _balance = address(this).balance;
        payable(i_owner).transfer(_balance);
      
        emit WithdrawFunds(i_owner, _balance);
    }

    // Function to restock the inventory
    // only the owner should be able to call this fn
    function restock() private onlyOwner {
        // update quantity of snacks
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < snackNames.length; i++) {
            string memory snackName = snackNames[i];
            Snacks storage snack = inventory[snackName];
            uint256 restockQuantity = INITIAL_QUANTITY - snack.quantity; // Checks if the restock quantity is greater than or equal to the needed quantity
            // checks whether the current snack quantity is less than the needed quantity
            if (snack.quantity < INITIAL_QUANTITY) {
                snack.quantity += restockQuantity;
            } else {
                revert VendingMachine__OverStock("No need to restock");
            }
        }
    }

    // Function to check the balance of the vending machine
    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```